# ibatis scriptrunner failing to create table-says invalid character

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am using ibatis SCRIPRunner which supports triggers and procedure for running my sql script on oracle db but some create statement are failing for with ivalid charcter can any one help me which character it is taking as invalid character

**Executing:**

```
ALTER TABLE BFTB_BUSINESSDATELOG ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BUSINESSDTLOG PRIMARY KEY (BFBUSINESSDATEIDPK); 
CREATE TABLE BFTB_CATEGORY
(
BFCATEGORYIDPK VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
BFCATEGORYTYPE VARCHAR(10),
BFDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(40),
VERSIONNUM INTEGER,
BFAPPLICATIONID VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Error: `ORA-00911: invalid character`

**Executing:**

```
ALTER TABLE BFTB_CATEGORY ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CATEGORY PRIMARY KEY (BFCATEGORYIDPK); 
CREATE TABLE BFTB_CTGARTEFACTLINK
(
BFLINKIDPK VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
BFARTEFACTNAME VARCHAR(256),
BFCATEGORYID VARCHAR(30),
VERSIONNUM INTEGER,
BFARTEFACTID VARCHAR(256),
BFAPPLICATIONID VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Error: `ORA-00911: invalid character`

## script runner

```
package com.rj.installer.action;



public class ScriptRunner {

  private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator","\n");

  private static final String DEFAULT_DELIMITER = ";";
  private FileOutputStream logFile ;
  private BufferedWriter writer ;

  private MyLogger logs ;

  private static final String S_N = "(\\s|\\n)+";
  private static final String IDENTIFIER = "(\\S+|\"[^\"]+\")";
  private static final String BLOCK_START = "(^|" + S_N + ")" +
            "create" + S_N +
            "(or" + S_N + "replace" + S_N + ")?" +
            "(function|library|package(" + S_N + "body)?|procedure|trigger|type)" + S_N +
            IDENTIFIER + S_N +
            ".*";

  private final Pattern blockStart = Pattern.compile(BLOCK_START, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

  private Connection connection;

  private boolean stopOnError;
  private boolean autoCommit;
  private boolean sendFullScript;

  private PrintWriter logWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
  private PrintWriter errorLogWriter = new PrintWriter(System.err);

  private String DatabaseProductName;
  private String delimiter = DEFAULT_DELIMITER;
  private boolean fullLineDelimiter = false;

  public ScriptRunner(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
    logs = new MyLogger("logs/sql.log");
  }

  public void setStopOnError(boolean stopOnError) {
    this.stopOnError = stopOnError;
  }

  public void setAutoCommit(boolean autoCommit) {
    this.autoCommit = autoCommit;
  }

  public void setSendFullScript(boolean sendFullScript) {
    this.sendFullScript = sendFullScript;
  }

  public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter logWriter) {
    this.logWriter = logWriter;
  }

  public void setErrorLogWriter(PrintWriter errorLogWriter) {
    this.errorLogWriter = errorLogWriter;
  }

  public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
  }

  public void setFullLineDelimiter(boolean fullLineDelimiter) {
    this.fullLineDelimiter = fullLineDelimiter;
  }

  public void runScript(Reader reader) {
    try {
      setAutoCommit();
      DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
        DatabaseProductName = md.getDatabaseProductName().toUpperCase().trim();
      try {
        if ("ORACLE".equals(DatabaseProductName)) {
          executeOracleScript(reader);    
        } else {
          if (sendFullScript) {
            executeFullScript(reader);
          } else {
            executeLineByLine(reader);
          }
         }
      } finally {
        rollbackConnection();
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      String message = "\nError retrieving database metadata\nCause: " + e;
      logs.writeFile(message);
      throw new RuntimeException(message, e);
    }

    logs.closeFile();
  }

  private void executeFullScript(Reader reader) {
    StringBuffer script = new StringBuffer();

    try {
      BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
      String line;
      while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
        script.append(line);
        script.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
      }
      executeStatement(script.toString());
      commitConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      String message = "\nError executing: \n" + script + "Cause: " + e;
      logs.writeFile(message);
      throw new RuntimeException(message, e);
    }
  }

  private void executeLineByLine(Reader reader) {
    StringBuffer command = new StringBuffer();
    try {
      BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
      String line;
      while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
        command = handleLine(command, line);
      }
      commitConnection();
      checkForMissingLineTerminator(command);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      String message = "\nError executing: \n" + command + "Cause: " + e;
      logs.writeFile(message);
      throw new RuntimeException(message, e);
    }
  }

  private void executeOracleScript(Reader reader) {
    StringBuffer command = new StringBuffer();
    try {
      boolean plsqlMode = false;
      BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
      String line;
      while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String trimmedLine = line.trim();
        if (trimmedLine.length() == 0) {
          continue;
        }
        if (trimmedLine.matches("[/.]")) {
          /*
            Terminate PL/SQL subprograms by entering a period (.) by itself on
            a new line. You can also terminate and execute a PL/SQL subprogram
            by entering a slash (/) by itself on a new line.
          */
          System.out.println("Executing Oracle Script");
          println(command);
          logs.writeFile("Executing : " +command.toString());
          String cm = command.toString();
          executeStatement(cm.trim());
          plsqlMode = false;
          command.setLength(0);
        } else if (!plsqlMode &&
                    (blockStart.matcher(command).find() ||
                     "begin".equalsIgnoreCase(line) ||
                     "declare".equalsIgnoreCase(line)
                    )
                  ) {
          plsqlMode = true;
          command.append(line);
          command.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        } else if (!plsqlMode &&
                    ( ("exit" + delimiter).equalsIgnoreCase(line) ||
                       "exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)
                    )
                  ) {
          return;
        } else if (!plsqlMode && line.endsWith(delimiter)) {
          command.append(line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(delimiter)));
          println(command);
          logs.writeFile("Executing : " +command.toString());
          executeStatement(command.toString().trim());
          command.setLength(0);
        } else {
          command.append(line);
          command.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }
      }
      // Check to see if we have an unexecuted statement in command.
      if (command.length() > 0) {
        println(command);
        logs.writeFile("Executing : " +command.toString());
        executeStatement(command.toString().trim());
      }
      commitConnection();
      checkForMissingLineTerminator(command);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      String message = "\nError executing: \n" + command + "Cause: " + e;
      logs.writeFile(message);
      throw new RuntimeException(message, e);
    }
  }

  public void run(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    try {
      stmt.execute(sql);
    } finally {
      try {
        stmt.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        //ignore
      }
    }
  }

  public void closeConnection() {
    try {
      connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // ignore
    }
  }

  private void setAutoCommit() {
    try {
      if (autoCommit != connection.getAutoCommit()) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
      }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not set AutoCommit to " + autoCommit + ". Cause: " + t, t);
    }
  }

  private void commitConnection() {
    try {
      if (!connection.getAutoCommit()) {
        connection.commit();
      }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not commit transaction. Cause: " + t, t);
    }
  }

  private void rollbackConnection() {
    try {
      if (!connection.getAutoCommit()) {
        connection.rollback();
      }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      // ignore
    }
  }

  private void checkForMissingLineTerminator(StringBuffer command) {
    if (command != null && command.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        logs.writeFile("Line missing end-of-line terminator (" + delimiter + ") => " + command);
      throw new RuntimeException("Line missing end-of-line terminator (" + delimiter + ") => " + command);
    }
  }

  private StringBuffer handleLine(StringBuffer command, String line) throws SQLException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String trimmedLine = line.trim();
    if (commandReadyToExecute(trimmedLine)) {
      command.append(line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(delimiter)));
      command.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
     logs.writeFile("Executing : " +command.toString());
      println(command);
      executeStatement(command.toString());
      command.setLength(0);
    } else if (trimmedLine.length() > 0) {
      command.append(line);
      command.append(LINE_SEPARATOR);
    }
    return command;
  }

  private boolean commandReadyToExecute(String trimmedLine) {
    return !fullLineDelimiter && trimmedLine.endsWith(delimiter)
        || fullLineDelimiter && trimmedLine.equals(delimiter);
  }

  private void executeStatement(String command) throws SQLException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    boolean hasResults = false;
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    if (stopOnError) {
      hasResults = statement.execute(command);
    } else {
      try {
        hasResults = statement.execute(command);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
          logs.writeFile("Error : " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
    printResults(statement, hasResults);
    try {
      statement.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Ignore to workaround a bug in some connection pools
    }
  }

  private void printResults(Statement statement, boolean hasResults) {
    try {
      if (hasResults) {
        ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
        if (rs != null) {
          ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
          int cols = md.getColumnCount();
          for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            String name = md.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
            print(name + "\t");
          }
          println("");
          while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
              String value = rs.getString(i + 1);
              print(value + "\t");
            }
            println("");
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logs.writeFile("Error : " + e.getMessage());
      printlnError("Error printing results: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private void print(Object o) {
    if (logWriter != null) {
      logWriter.print(o);
      logWriter.flush();
    }
  }

  private void println(Object o) {
    if (logWriter != null) {
      logWriter.println(o);
      logWriter.flush();
    }
  }

  private void printlnError(Object o) {
    if (errorLogWriter != null) {
      errorLogWriter.println(o);
      errorLogWriter.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that.

ScriptRunner send line by line to DB. When the script has a delimiter ($$, &&, ||), the line is automatically executed. To fix this, you need to use the last version of ScriptRunner and set to send full script (runner.setSendFullScript(true)).